# Azure Streaming Returning Data

Tags: azure, azure-stream-analytics, cortana-intelligence

How can azure stream return the processed data in real-time? I see most examples pushing processed data back to a DB or dashboard. I need everything to happen in real-time for a single request (step 4). How do you achieve this with minimal latency? Example below:

1) Page requested by client 
2) Page sends some data to azure stream
3) Azure Stream does logic and calculations with data and data from 5 second window
4) Sends result back to Page so it can perform some IMMEDIATE action
5) Stores result in database for reporting

Answer (score 1):

You can set the output to be an Azure Service Bus EventHub, Queue, or Topic and have your application monitoring one of those outputs.  The workflow would be something like:

1. Page requested by client
2. Page sends data to ASA (Azure Stream Analytics). *Note: you are really sending data to an Azure Event Hub which has an ASA job running with the EH as an input.*
3. The ASA job does it's logic / query and outputs to a different Azure EventHub (or Queue or Topic).
4. You have a Web Job or server side job monitoring the output EventHub and use websockets to relay that information back to the client.

You can find some example code on the [Microsoft Connect the Dots](https://msopentech.com/blog/2014/12/10/connecthedots-io/) example. In this example IoT devices are sending weather data to an Azure EventHub and there is an ASP.NET site that is monitoring that EventHub and through websockets updating the clients.